# C# WPF FileInfo Media Source?

Tags: c#, uri, media-player

When I'm get .mp3 file without path but I couldn't play Uri got some errors. My codes;

```
private void listbox2_Drop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
try
{
    string[] a = (string[])(e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop, false));
    foreach (var names in a)
    {
        FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(names);
        if (fileInfo.Extension == ".MP3" ||fileInfo.Extension == ".mp3")
        {
            listbox2.Items.Add(   fileInfo.Name);
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception)
{}
}

private void listbox2_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{      
    object listboxİtems = listbox2.SelectedItem;
    if (listboxİtems != null)
    {
        media2.Source = new Uri(listboxİtems.ToString(),    UriKind.Relative); // I'm getting erors here
        media2.Play();
    }
}
```

he got error at media2.Source that listboxItems.ToString() string is unable to play

Comment: what "listboxİtems.ToString()" gives ?

Answer (score 0):

Just add the full `FileInfo` object to your Items.

Then you have the full object to build your `Uri` with `FullPath` or `DirectoryName` and `Name`.

Finally, define your `ListBox.ItemTemplate` to something that suits your needs (like a `TextBlock` bound to the `Name` property)

Here goes some of the requested code :

```
private void listbox2_Drop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
try
{
    string[] a = (string[])(e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop, false));
    foreach (var names in a)
    {
        FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(names);
        if (fileInfo.Extension == ".MP3" ||fileInfo.Extension == ".mp3")
        {
            listbox2.Items.Add(fileInfo); //store the full FileInfo in your Items, not just the Name property
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception)
{}
}

private void listbox2_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{      
    FileInfo listboxItem = listbox2.SelectedItem as FileInfo; //cast the SelectedItem to the FileInfo type
    if (listboxItem != null)
    {
        media2.Open(new Uri(listboxItem.FullPath, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute)); // if I remember well, Source is Read-Only, use Open instead
        media2.Play();
    }
}
```

And the suggested XAML for the ListBox :

```
<ListBox>
     <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
               <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
          </DataTemplate>
     </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: media2.Open? İ cant find this method?

Comment: Well, not sure of what your UI elements are. I've supposed, maybe wrongly, this was a System.Windows.Media.MediaPlayer. Very same for the ListBox I assumed to be WPF/Silverlight. The interesting part is to store the full FileInfo  on drop and then use it to build the Uri.